# how to change LastWriteTime in a script?

Tags: powershell

am trying to create a script (chgdate.ps1) to change the LastWriteTime property of a file:

```
Get-ChildItem $args[0]| % {$_.LastWriteTime = $args[1]}
```

but when I run it with eg:

```
chgdate.ps1 "e:\temp\testfile" "01-01-2024 19:27:00"
```

I get this error:

```
    Exception setting "LastWriteTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At d:\my documents\bat\chgdate.ps1:3 char:30
+  Get-ChildItem $args[0] | % {$_.LastWriteTime = $args[1]}
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Scope issue, you cannot call `$args` from inside the `Foreach-Object` scriptblock.

```
$Path = $args[0]
$NewWriteTime = $args[1]
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path ) | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime = $NewWriteTime }
```

Comment: I got a whole bunch of the following errors with your solution:

SetValueInvocationException: D:\My Documents\bat\chgdate.ps1:4
Line |
   4 |      ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime = $NewWriteTime }
     |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception setting "LastWriteTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."

Comment: `.LastWriteTime` expects either a `[DateTime]` value or at least a string convertible to that.   

What value are you passing to it? Because with "01-01-2024 19:27:00" it works perfectly on my system, both powershell 5.1 and 7.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a string as an argument, not a date object. Just use Get-Date, f.e.:

```
$Path = $args[0]
$NewWriteTime = $args[1]
Get-ChildItem $Path | % {$_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date $NewWriteTime)}
```

Comment: I got this error with your solution:
Get-Date: D:\My Documents\bat\chgdate.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  Get-ChildItem $args[0]| % {$_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date $args[1])}
     |                                                          ~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type
     | "System.DateTime"."

Comment: in this case, try to combine both solutions, I changed script in my answer